# Does python count deleted items?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
WF={"Angel Falls":3211.7, "Tugela Falls":3110.2, "Three Sisters Fall":2998.5, "Olo'supena Falls":2953.3, "Yumbilla Falls":2940}
```

Referring to above, when I have delete the "Angel Falls" using code below:

```
Waterfall = dict(WF)
del Waterfall["Angel Falls"]
print(len(WF))
```

It will give me an answer of 5. Why it is not 4 instead since I have deleted one item in the dict?

Comment: waterfall became a copy when you shoved a dict constructor over wf.  use `Waterfall = WF`

Comment: Because you are modifying `Waterfall`, not `WF`. `Waterfall` is a copy of `WF` and does not reference the same underlying object. You can see that it is a copy by using `Waterfall is WF` and seeing that it is `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Waterfall = dict(WF) create a copy of WF dictionary.

So you have 2 objects :

- WF
- Waterfall

Your remove operation is on Waterfall dict object.

Then you print the WF dict object which has not changed.

Print Waterfall to view change.